# Can't link to high address with cargo xbuild

Tags: rust

I'm trying to link a program to high address (>4G) with cargo xbuild but no success. 
I use cargo xbuild to cross-compile my code to bare-metal. It's seem that the core crate is compiled with small code mode, but I'm not sure about that.

Here is the errors:

```
   Compiling main v0.1.0 (/home/william/tmp/test/ex)
error: linking with `rust-lld` failed: exit code: 1
  = note: rust-lld: error: core.8lixb224-cgu.5:(function core::panicking::panic::hc11320c428d64a0e: .text._ZN4core9panicking5panic17hc11320c428d64a0eE+0x2F): relocation R_X86_64_32S out of range: -140737488355208 is not in [-2147483648, 2147483647]
          rust-lld: error: core.8lixb224-cgu.5:(function core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha877ab6e0ac893c4: .text._ZN4core9panicking9panic_fmt17ha877ab6e0ac893c4E+0x9): relocation R_X86_64_32S out of range: -140737488355208 is not in [-2147483648, 2147483647]
          rust-lld: error: core.8lixb224-cgu.5:(function core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha877ab6e0ac893c4: .text._ZN4core9panicking9panic_fmt17ha877ab6e0ac893c4E+0x12): relocation R_X86_64_32S out of range: -140737488355208 is not in [-2147483648, 2147483647]
```

rustc --version: `rustc 1.44.0-nightly (1edd389cc 2020-03-23)`

Minimal example:

`ls`

```
Cargo.toml  link.ld  main.rs  rust-toolchain  x86_64-unknown-none.json
```

main.rs:

```
#![no_std]                                  // don't link the Rust standard library
#![no_main]                                 // disable all Rust-level entry points
use core::panic::PanicInfo;
mod aaa {
    static A: usize = 10;
    static mut B: u128 = 0;

    pub fn a_func () {  
        unsafe {
            B = ((&A as *const usize as usize  as u128)<<16) + (0 as u128)*8 - 1;
        }
    }
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn _start () -> ! {
    aaa::a_func ();
    loop {}
}

#[panic_handler]
pub fn my_panic_handler (_panic_info: &PanicInfo) -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

x86_64-unknown-none.json:

```
{
  "llvm-target": "x86_64-unknown-none",
  "data-layout": "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128",
  "arch": "x86_64",
  "target-endian": "little",
  "target-pointer-width": "64",
  "target-c-int-width": "32",
  "os": "none",
  "executables": true,
  "relocation-model": "static",
  "code-model": "large",
  "linker-flavor": "ld.lld",
  "linker": "rust-lld",
  "panic-strategy": "abort",
  "disable-redzone": true,
  "features": "-mmx,-sse,+soft-float"
}
```

link.ld:

```
PHDRS
{
    load PT_LOAD;
}

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0xffff800000000000;

    .text : { *(.text) }
    .data : { *(.data) *(.rodata) }
    .bss : { *(.bss) }

    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_frame) *(.comment) }
}
```

rust-toolchain:

```
nightly-2020-03-24
```

Build with this command: `cargo xbuild --target x86_64-unknown-none`